# NHibernate ID Column needed?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Iam still quite new to Nhibernate and I have a question regarding the ID columns.

Lets think about the folling class customer:

```
class customer
{
    public virtual long ID;
    public virtual string Name;

    public customer()
    {

    }

    public customer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

In the Mapping files I have defined, that the ID column is beeing generated.
So I want to create a new Customer with:

```
customer c = new customer("Max Mustermann");
```

Everything ist Ok now. The ID is generated and Max can be saved into the DB.
But there is also the possibility of generating a customer like this:

```
customer c = new customer() { ID = 3, Name= "Max Mustermann"};
```

This should not be possible, because I really cant know the DB-ID of the Customer (only his Name). Furthermore I really dont need the ID in my programm and so im not happy having the ID in my object.

In my opinion this is a bad class design in Nhibernate ... Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

**edit 1:**

Is that what u mean?

```
class customer
{
    protected virtual long _ID;
    public virtual string Name;

    public virtual long GetID 
    {
        get { return _ID; } 
    }

    public customer()
    {

    }

    public customer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Would that work? How would a Mapping file look like?

Comment: Shouldn't `private virtual long ID;` help?

Comment: you could map your Id as a protected (not private) property instead of a public one and provide a public property with only a getter so that you can still access the Id if needed.

Comment: related to the edit: yes, something like that. You would just map _ID instead of the ID property (or field, in your case) you mapped before. And GetID would not be mapped at all.

Comment: tried and worked well. Thx alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that this is "bad class design in NHibernate," but the class *has* to be designed like this.  When NHibernate is querying your database and turning each row into a concrete class, it needs to be able to set the `ID` property to the value given by the database.  Thus, there is a *requirement* for that value to be settable.

It is also possible to insert rows into a database (in most database engines) with identity constraints temporarily disabled - so it *is* possible to know the ID in advance.

This is one of the (many!) conceptual difficulties that an ORM has to overcome, and the fact that there are often some "loose edges" like this are an indication of how complex these problems are.

To turn the question around: can you think of a class design that would prevent ID being set without compromising the other functionality that NHibernate provides?

Comment: Not really :). I just asked whether there is a workaround or somethink like that, but GarlandGreene already provided it.